# linq to sharepoint datacontext ignore user permission

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint-2010

I'm useing 'Linq to SharePoint' and when I get a SharePoint context the list is empty (user haven't permission to this list).

```
using (SystemOcenContextDataContext ctx = new SystemOcenContextDataContext("url"))
{
    // my code
}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SystemOcenContextDataContext ctx = new SystemOcenContextDataContext("url"))
    {
        // my code
    }
});
```

but the context lists are still empty :( Any ideas?

Comment: tag with sharepoint version please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is another bug :) I find solution:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2010/09/19/linq-to-sharepoint-and-runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx